# Using setState for showing an API response causes an infinite loop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm developing an app using MERN (MongoDB,Express, React an Node.js), and I'm trying to write a very simple functional component, which uses a setState hook just to show the response of an API after calling a method implemented on this one.
It's just a very simple component implemented just for the purpose of resetting the database without using tools like the MongoDB Shell or MongoDB compass, every time I need to.

I'm trying this:

File "resetear-componente.js":

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Resetear = () => {
    const [resData, setResData] = useState('');

    if (window.confirm("¿Realmente desea resetear la base de datos?")) {
        //In english: "Are you sure you want to reset the database?"
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/resetear')
        .then(respuesta=> {
            setResData(respuesta.data);
        })
        .catch(res => {



            if(res.code=="ERR_BAD_REQUEST") {
                setResData(res.response.data);
            }

            else {
                setResData(res.message);
            }

            console.log(res);
        });

    })
    return (
           <div >
                {resData}
            </div>
           );

}

export default Resetear;
```

This component is routed in another file like this:

```
...
import Resetear from "./resetear.componente";
...
    <Switch>
    ...
       <Route path="/resetear" exact component={Resetear} />
    ...
</Switch>
...
```

Finally, the get method implemented at the API in the file "server.js" is this one:

```
...
//Implemento una ruta para resetear la base de datos
app.get('/resetear', function(req, res) {
            inicializarDb.resetear(connection);
            return res.json("Base reseteada")
        }
    );
...
```

So then, every time I go to the path "http://localhost:3000/resetear", where the component is routed, I get an infinite loop showing the confirm box.
What I'm doing wrong?

I don't know if this is correct or if there's a better way to do this.

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Put the data fetching section into useEffect to ensure that it is executed when the component is mounted, if you enable React Strict Mode, the confirmation popup may appear twice.

```
const Resetear = () => {
  const [resData, setResData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const confirmed = window.confirm(
      '¿Realmente desea resetear la base de datos?'
    );
    
    if (confirmed) {
      axios
        .get('http://localhost:5000/resetear')
        .then((respuesta) => {
          setResData(respuesta.data);
        })
        .catch((res) => {
          if (res.code == 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST') {
            setResData(res.response.data);
          } else {
            setResData(res.message);
          }

          console.log(res);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  return <div>{resData}</div>;
};
```